# Why MySQL having clause omitting zero

Tags: mysql

My [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6517f/6) is here.

Work around :
My table structure is

```
create table test (grIds int(1), amount int(1));
insert into test values
(1,10),
(1,20),
(1,15),
(2,0),
(3,8),
(3,25),
(3,16),
(4,0),
(4,21);
```

I have two select clause

```
select grIds, max(amount) from test
group by grIds having max(amount);

select grIds, max(amount) from test
group by grIds;
```

My question is why select with having keeps omitting row having grIds = 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

HAVING clauses can place extra restrictions on the output rows of an aggregate query – just like WHERE clauses do in record-by-record queries. A HAVING clause can impose conditions on any output column or combination of columns, aggregate or not.

As far as NULL is concerned, the following two facts are worth knowing (and hardly surprising, I would guess):

Rows for which the HAVING condition evaluates to NULL won't be included in the result set. (“Only true is good enough.”)

“HAVING  IS [NOT] NULL” is a legal and often useful condition, whether  is aggregate or not. (But if  is non-aggregate, you may save the engine some work by changing HAVING to WHERE and placing the condition before the “GROUP BY” clause. This goes for any condition on non-aggregate columns.)

**Remarks**

MAX ignores any null values.
For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.

Comment: There are no nulls here, but I believe only the classic "0 evaluates to false" in boolean context.

Comment: @Mat that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer and the commenters explained the reason for the having behavior. I was wondering what you actually wanted to do, is it this:

```
SELECT grIds, MAX(amount) maxa 
FROM test 
GROUP BY grIds 
ORDER BY maxa DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Would have left a comment instead - alas, not enough points yet.

Comment: No. I just need to know why it is happening